# Printing two pages per sheet, how to keep first page on the right side in OpenOffice?

Tags: printing, openoffice

I'm writing a book with OpenOffice 4.1.1 and I'd like to print sheets of the book for proofreading. The book uses page styles extensively and the first page is set to be the right page. I can select to print two pages per sheet, but that makes the first page print on the left, and once that happens, all right pages are printed on the left side and left pages are printed on the right side.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Booklet printing completely messes up the page order. I won't be
  stapling this into a booklet.
- Changing the page order doesn't help

Is there a clean and simple way to do it?

Comment: If I got right what you looking for then just add one empty page as a first page, then that one that supposed to be first will be printed on the right

Comment: @Alex, hmm.. Another blank page gets added and the pages remain in wrong sides, also page numbering gets changed, but let's see if those problems could be tweaked away..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out how to do it. It's not clean, simple or elegant but it works as a stopgap measure.

- Add a new page into the beginning
- Another empty page gets added as a left page
- Page numbering changes, work around this by editing the first paragraph of the text to set page number 1 (Format -> Paragraph -> Text Flow -> Breaks -> Insert "Page" With Page Style "First Page", Page Number "1"
- Go to Print menu
- in [Page Layout] tab, select Pages Per Sheet: 2
- in [OpenOffice Writer] tab, select [X] Print automatically inserted blank pages
- in [General] tab, set print range from page 2 to whatever the last page number is